# Converting Javascript 'namespaces' over multiple ES modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In some older codes I 'namespaced' shared methods like this (assuming `mycomp` is a company name):

```
//File mycomp-common.js
var mycomp = window.mycomp || {};

mycomp.common = {

    //shared methods and constants
    someMethod: function() {
       ...
    }
};


//File mycomp-myapp-common.js
var mycomp = window.mycomp || {};
mycomp.myapp = mycomp.myapp || {};

mycomp.myapp.common = {

    //shared methods and constants for myapp
    someOtherMethod: function() {
       ...
    }
};
```

As you can see both files make sure that the main namespace `mycomp` exists. The first file places company wide utilities in the main namespace. The second file creates an application specific sub-namespace and places its shared methods there. These files are currently loaded top-level in my index.html.

The consuming code accesses methods like this

```
let result = mycomp.myapp.someOtherMethod();
```

How do I convert these codes to ES modules for better modularization, lazy loading and bundling?

Comment: Just drop all the namespace stuff, and have a module for each unit. You might still organise your file system hierarchy like the nested namespaces you had. Do not assume "*that the main `mycomp` exists*" because something should have loaded it before, no, just explicitly import the utilities module when you need them.

Comment: Ok, but what does this mean regarding namespace clashes when calling methods. If I understand you correctly I would have something like 'import * from "mycomp"' in the caller and then "let result = someMethod()". But that means "someMethod()" can easily clash with some other method. I could use 'import * as mycomp from "mycomp"' but that would mean it's the clients responsibility to take care of this.

Comment: There is no `import * from`. Yes, you always need to give an alias to the import, and yes this is (and should be) the responsibility of the user of the module.