# Can I convert nested namespacing design pattern to es6 module pattern?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have an existing code with multiple JS files. Each file adds new property with object literal onto global namespace. It seems bunch of Java developers worked on this project looking at the pattern where you would end up with a method foo in App.product.foo()

Current (as is) code:

```
// product.js
var app = app || {};
app.product = {
  changeColor = function(e) {};
  clickEventHandler = function() {
    app.cart.addToCart(e.target.dataset['code']);
  };
}

// cart.js
var app = app || {};
app.cart = {
  addToCart = function(productCode) {}
}
```

Can I convert this into ES6 modules pattern so that I can export / import required code across modules?

```
// product.js
import { addToCart } from './cart';

export default {
  changeColor = function(e) {};
  clickEventHandler = function() {
    addToCart(e.target.dataset['code']);
  };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Javascript 'namespaces' over multiple ES modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62910519/1048572) and [the following discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63042939/1048572)

Comment: Yes, you can convert this to ES6 modules, but it will be quite different when you have to explicitly declare your dependencies instead of just assuming that methods on your namespace objects will be available. And no, you should not default-export object literals, you should `export function changeColor(e) {}` and `export function clickEventHanlder(e) { … }`.

Comment: Thank you Bergi for your response. I just noticed out that few third party addons are also written assuming these namespace objects will be available :(
I am assuming, it's just impossible to convert witht that dependency?

Comment: The alternative might be to rewrite your code to ES6 modules, then in your main.js build that (nested) namespace object with the methods that you want/need to expose and install it on `window.app`.

Comment: Okay, makes sense!
I am assuming having namespace object is not a recommended approach isn't it?

Comment: Not if you can avoid it. Notice you can still get namespace objects for each module by using `import * as namespace from …`

Comment: @Bergi can you post as answer? Will mark it as solved